# Multiple Google Maps won't work with Bootstrap 3 Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, tabs

I got this code working but it won't work on Bootstrap 3 `Tabs` and can't seem to figure out what the issue is! It feels like the Tabs Javascript is the issue but the console doesn't show any error!

I'm at my wits end as to why the second tab doesn't load when I put the code in the Tab but both the maps work when I remove from the tab.

How do I resolve this issue?

```
CODEPEN with Tab: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwzBym
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <h5>Some Text here</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="contactus">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#registered">Office1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#branch">Office2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="registered" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="branch" class="tab-pane fade">
          <div id="gmap_canvas2" style="height:300px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            styles: [{
                stylers: [{
                    saturation: -50
                }]
            }],
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.676028, 77.098720),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var myOptions2 = {
            zoom: 10,
            styles: [{
                stylers: [{
                    saturation: -50
                }]
            }],
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.843651, 80.949111),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas2'), myOptions2);

        //FIRST MARKER

        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.676028, 77.098720)
        });
        infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Office 1'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
            infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
        });
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);


        //SECOND MARKER

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map2,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.843651, 80.949111)
        });
        infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Office 2'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);
        });
        infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

When I remove the DIV that accompanies the tab script, it works as shown below:

```
Working CODEPEN without Tab: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLRbrp
```

Comment: I  know it's not correct. Simply adding active to your branch tab it works [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5049vbow/)

Comment: Could you post that as answer? I would like to say it resolved it in the most elegant way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unshown tab is a div not yet rendered. You need to trigger the rendering of the hidden tab's map with the **resize** function from the API: add the following to your code - it checks for the heading of the shown tab and triggers the corresponding map's **resize**:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
   if( $(event.target).text() == 'Office2')
       {
         google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
         map2.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(22.843651, 80.949111) );
       }
   else if( $(event.target).text() == 'Office')
       {
         google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
         map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(22.676028, 77.098720) );
       }
});
```

Working codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NarKyO

Comment: Nice! How do I center align the marker in the second map? It currently throws the marker to the upper left corner.

Comment: See the edit. To prevent that side-effect, simply set the center again.